# Power BI: How to Create a Matrix with Row Headers = Data label, Column Headers = Measures

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset consist of two **time series**: e.g. Historical stock prices for Apple and Microsoft. And I have a few different power BI **measures** created for **each** of these two stocks (e.g. Weekly Return, Monthly Return).

I want to create a "Matrix"-like visual, to show:

- stock names as the row headers
- measures as the column headers
- values being the corresponding measure value for the given date selected on a date slicer

To illustrate what I want to do, please see the picture from Excel as an example. Is there a convenient way to do this in Power BI?

Thank you very much for your help!

[Excel illustration on what the visual should look like in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM33G.png)